# How to uninstall apps that added using ./install command?

Tags: software-installation, uninstall

I added VMware using

`user#  ./VMwarexxxxx.bundle`

Now I don't know how to uninstall it? I also used the following commands:

`user# chmod +x VMware-Workstation`

Answer (score 0):

"./" isn't a command, but a path.  A "." means "here, in this directory" and the "/" is just the standard path separator.  So "./[name]" means "run [name] that's located in the current directory".

VMWare bundles include an executable you can use to uninstall.  Try         `vmware-installer -u vmware-workstation` or `./VMwarexxxxx.bundle -u vmware-workstation`